# How to show a UIPicker on click of a text field in a particular table view cell swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am having a table view controller with a custom prototype cell.The prototype cell has one textfield on the left(**Heading**) and another textfield on the right(**Value**).

This table view displays various details of a person with **Heading** on the left and **Value** on the right.The user can edit 3 fields on this page like Policy Holder, Name and Phone Number.This table view has around 15 rows.

When user wants to edit Policy Holder and when he clicks on the the textfield at right side of Policy Holder I want to show a UIPikcer with two options like Self & Other. Once user selects any one among them it has to be entered into the text field.

And if user wants to edit Phone Number field I want the user to enter only in a specific format like +x (xxx) xxx-xxxx.

How can I do these things.

[image: My Table View UI looks like this]

Comment: I would suggest using - https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to implement this,
1) you can put button and textfield on the same cell and use hide/show feature accordingly.
2)In another option in the following textfield method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Add this

```
textField.inputView = _pickerView;
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

So you need to present a `UIPicker` on `UITextField` click, alright?

The first step is implement `UITextField`delegate and tag identifier to catch exactly what you need

Something like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
.
.
.
self.textField.delegate = self
self.textField.tag = indexPath.row
```

PS*: Maybe you should set delegate and tags on your cellForRow at indexPath(or similar)

After this, implement this method:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
// do this, not recommended
if textField.tag == xx {
   self.textField.inputView = yourPicker
   }
// the correct way is catch your cell indexPath at this point
}
```

I really hope that helped you, happy code =D